# How to make use of protected ranges in Google App Script?

Tags: range, google-apps-script, protected

As of 8th august it is possible to have protected ranges in spreadsheets. How can I access this functionality in my scripts? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would say you might simply need to wait for GAS to "catch up" with new features in Google Spreadsheets, or perhaps raise this as a feature request in the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).

If it were to be implemented, I presume it would as a setProtection() method on a range object, as it can be done now on a sheet object.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your attention on my other question. I removed it but since I'm not sure you received my comments as they are deleted along with the thread I wanted to apologise for this quite bad question... I guess I've been working too long on this script and began to loose some details ;-)

Comment: Haha no problem Serge, I saw your comments but didn't have an opportunity to reply; I know what you mean about missing small details in a big script.